# how to change the application name on the top

Tags: android

Every screen in my app shows correct app name but 1 screen shows a different name, thats because i copy pasted the code for that activity from a different app. now how to change it??

Comment: Can you show the code of that Activity..?

Comment: my xml for that screen is fine....it does not contain any app name

Comment: @Mudassir everytime no need code for solved issue..

Comment: If you set Title inside your Activity static way , you need to add title in all Activity where you want to show that Text. So you should use String.xml , this will reflect in all the Activities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

Write this code in your onCreate() method.

```
this.setTitle("Your Title");
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of setting in all Activity separately you can set it in **String.xml** as below snippet :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <string name="app_name">You App Name</string>
</resources>
```

In addition to it you should add in Manifest File

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

Comment: That is not the Standard way of setting Title for the Application , you should use Resources, then only you can use it throughout the Application if you need any changes

Comment: FYI there can be multiple way of achieving the Results.

Comment: We all know that there are many approach to solve that problem but Venky's solution is more advisable to use than yours. Why are you commenting all the other answers that are different from your answer? Everyone's going to see this question, and may requires another solution. Think of the future viewers.

Comment: @Venky if I want two diff title base on condition then how can i use withing resource? like as when page is loading I want to display title as "Loading" & when data will load completed then I want to display "Title".. How can I achieve this via resource ??

Comment: then the problem you are trying to solve is not archie's problem.

Comment: @CapDroid If we want to show different titles in a activity then your solution is good. But here, particularly for this question(where application name remains same for all the activity) we have to set title either in manifest or in strings.xml. Setting in each activity is not the standard way even we get the result

Comment: @CapDroid You should check the user question , he need to show same Title for all Activity but he is getting different title in only one Activity. So to get same Title we should use string.xml

Comment: @CapDroid Its ok mate. But even if someone post correct answer, we can post other way of achieving the same thing right. But commenting on the others solution is not good. If its correct, we have to accept. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Or it may also be changes through manifest where you put the activity tag

by : attribute:  android:label

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Answer (score 0):

Go to ***AndroidManifest.xml***.

Check your **Activity** if it has the correct `android:label`.

Comment: @CapDroid  It doesn't mean that we should not provide alternate solutions if any.